# Color gradient on one contour line

Tags: python, animation, gradient, contour

I'm very very new to Python, i usually do my animations with AfterEffects, but it requires a lot of computation time for quite simple things.

• So I would like to create this kind of animation (or at least image) :
[AfterEffects graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PR4Hc.jpg) (forget the shadows, i don't really need it at this point)

Those are circles **merging** together as they collide, **one of them being highlighted** (the orange one).

• For now i only managed to do the "merging thing" computing a "distance map" and ploting a contour line :
[Python + Matplotlib graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rm2U8.png) with the following code :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

part_size = 0.0002
nb_part = 200
mesh_res = 500      # resolution of grid


x = np.linspace(0, 1.9, mesh_res)
y = np.linspace(0, 1, mesh_res)
Xgrid, Ygrid = np.meshgrid(x, y)

centers = np.random.uniform(0,1,(nb_part,2))    # array filled with disks centers positions
sizes = part_size*np.ones(nb_part)              # array filled whith disks sizes
#sizes = np.random.uniform(0,part_size,nb_part)

dist_map = np.zeros((mesh_res,mesh_res),float)  # array to plot the contour of
for i in range(nb_part):
    dist_map += sizes[i] / ((Xgrid - centers[i][0]) ** 2 + (Ygrid - centers[i][1]) ** 2)    # function with (almost) value of 1 when on a cricle, so we want the contour of this array


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
contour_opts = {'levels': np.linspace(0.9, 1., 1), 'color':'red', 'linewidths': 4}  # to plot only the one-ish values of contour
ax.contour(x, y, dist_map, **contour_opts)


def update(frame_number):
    ax.collections = []     # reset the graph
    centers[:] += 0.01*np.sin(2*np.pi*frame_number/100+np.stack((np.arange(nb_part),np.arange(nb_part)),axis=-1)) # just to move circles "randomly"

    dist_map = np.zeros((mesh_res, mesh_res), float)    # updating array of distances
    for i in range(nb_part):
        dist_map += sizes[i] / ((Xgrid - centers[i][0]) ** 2 + (Ygrid - centers[i][1]) ** 2)

    ax.contour(x, y, dist_map, **contour_opts)  # calculate the new contour

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, interval=20)
plt.show()
```

The result is not that bad but :

1. i can't figure **how to highlight just one circle** keeping the merging effect (ideally, the colors should merge as well, and i would like to keep the image transparency when exported)
2. it still requires some time to compute each frame (it is way faster than AfterEffects though), so i guess i'm still very far from using optimally python, numpy, and matplotlib. Maybe there are even libraries able to do that kind of things ? So if there is a **better strategy** to implement it, i'll take it.